# How to write a proof for this?

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-measure

Prove or disprove that if $A\subset [0, 1]$ and $m(A) > 0$, then there are $x$ and $y$ in $A$ such that:

$$|x− y| $$

Is an irrational number.

I know this is true as if there were only rationals then measure would be zero 
but how do I prove it rigorously ? How do I write it down ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Fix $x \in A$. If $|x-y|$ is rational for  every $y \in A$ what can we say about the cardinality of $A$?

Comment: So you mean I go by the technique of contradiction, and assume that it isn't true and then show using your argument that m(A) =0 which turns out to be a contradiction to the hypothesis ?

Comment: Yes, prove it by contradiction. Deduce that $A$ is countable,.hence has measure $0$. @NihirAgarwal